# Configuring GeoServer SQL Views and Validation

Tags: data-validation

For a little background i want to mention that I am using GeoEXT with Geoserver. 
I am using the Geoext comboboxes to search point data by name. The application works properly for name having single name such as 'Khan' but it doesn't work for words having spaces like 'Not Khan'. I am herby writing the query and the parameters.

**Geoserver SQL View:**

```
select *
   from %Table%
WHERE
   to_tsvector('english', Column1) @@
   to_tsquery('english', regexp_replace(trim('%WordPassed%'), E'\\s+', '&', 'g'))
```

The above query work perfectly for texts having no spaces but doesn't work on names having spaces. 
The Validation used by Geoserver by default on that column is :

```
^[\w\d\s]+$
```

Comment: this is really a database question, GeoServer does nothing but pass your SQL to the database. It will help if you specify which database you are using.

Comment: @iant `to_tsquery()` looks like Postgres